# How to mount NFS share in OS X Yosemite?

Tags: linux, macos, centos, mount, nfs

I have an NFS server (CentOS 6.6 at IP 192.168.1.16) that shares a folder **/nfs/share**.

I want to mount this folder from a Mac laptop (at mount point **/nfs/share**).

When I tried the following:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o rw,sync,resvport 192.168.1.16:/nfs/share /nfs/share/
```

(both with or without 'resvport' option) I got an error:

```
mount_nfs: can't mount /nfs/share from 192.168.1.16 onto /nfs/share: Connection refused
```

The NFS server should be properly configured as I have no problem mounting the share from a CentOS computer.

The content of **/etc/exports** looks like this:

```
/nfs/share    192.168.1.1/24(rw,sync)
```

**UPDATE**: finally found that on the NFS server **/etc/exports**, I need to add **insecure** as an option:

```
/nfs/share    192.168.1.1/24(rw,sync,insecure)
```

Apparently this is needed to allow Mac OS X client to connect and according to some it's "not otherwise insecure" but others have claimed that it should not be used.

Comment: Rather than posting a potential solution in your question it would be better for you to post it as an answer.